# regex rule for email validation is not working in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I tried this code as provided in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html.

```
validEmail: function (email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Vuejs is saying that - `error: Unnecessary escape character: \[ (no-useless-escape) at src/components/form.vue:125:65` which is the line `var re = ...`

What I am getting wrong here? I called this function like `this.validEmail(this.modelname)`

Comment: So why don't you just remove the backslash? You're inside of a capture group. The only bracket to be escaped is the closing bracket ].

Comment: @lher I removed all `\` which are before of [ and ], and it comes with other characters to ...

Comment: Escaping means adding a backslash \ before a character. The bracket [ is escaped by adding a backslash \  character >> \\[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "error" (technically it's just a warning) is saying that you do not need to escape `[` in the regex when it is inside a character set (`[]` syntax) because its meaning is unambiguous (you can't create nested character sets); `]`, on the other hand, *does* need to be escaped because it will be interpreted as part of the regex syntax that ends the character set instead of a literal `]` character.

Simplified example:

```
/[\[]/
  ^ unnecessary escape
```

should be instead:

```
/[[]/
```

Comment: I tried after removing `\[\]` and again it said same error message with \. and \- . After all done and no error was there but email validation does not work.

Comment: Right, now you're getting similar errors for other unnecessary escapes – remove them too. `.` does not need to be escaped in a character set. With `-` I usually put it first after the `[` so it needn't be escaped.

Comment: I tried that did not work ... error gone but ... validation did not work

Comment: You should only be removing the ``\`` character where indicated.