# How can i validate email in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

[regex rule for email validation is not working in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592444/regex-rule-for-email-validation-is-not-working-in-vuejs)

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
<div class="email-icon"></div>

<input type="email"  v-model.trim="$v.email.$model"
 v-validate="'required'"
:class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.email) }"
 name="email" class=" input-section" 
placeholder="Enter your company email ID"
:maxlength="maxemail"
v-on:keypress="validEmail($event)"
 id='email'  v-model='email' />
 
<div v-if="!$v.email.required" class="invalid-feedback">
The email field is required.</div>
                 
<div v-if="!$v.email.maxLength" class="invalid-feedback-register">
 30 characters only  {{ $v.user.password.$params.maxLength.min }} </div>
</div>
```

I tried checking with [regex rule for email validation is not working in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592444/regex-rule-for-email-validation-is-not-working-in-vuejs)   but unable to solve the issue.

I want email to mandatory to check domain name, example:- abc@gmail.com,
tried taking one keypress event where i am unable to passs regex as given in the link

Answer (score 3):

I always use [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/). Easy and simple.
You can do the maxlength and much more! Additionally, you are even able to check, which parts are 'dirty' in the Vue Devtools!
Example code:

```
<template>
   <input required="required" v-model="email" :error-messages="emailErrors"
   @input="$v.email.$touch()" @blur="$v.email.$touch()" label="Email*"
   prepend-icon="mdi-email"></input>
</template>

<script>
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
import { required, email, ... } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {

mixins: [validationMixin],
validations: {
    ...,
    email: { required, email },
    ...
},
data: () => ({ email: '', ... })
computed: {
    emailErrors () {
        const errors = []
        if (!this.$v.email.$dirty) return errors
        !this.$v.email.email && errors.push('Must be valid e-mail')
        !this.$v.email.required && errors.push('E-mail is required')
        return errors
    },
}
```

Comment: In computed property i have  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){

      return (this.fullname  <= this.max) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
      || (this.gstin.length < this.maxgstin) ||
       (this.email <= this.maxemail) || !this.terms || !(this.verified == true );

Comment: Can i set as to disabled until user enter valid email

Comment: What do you want to disable? But yes you can. 
For that, you can simply use the computed `$v.$anydirty` (when checking for all fields in the form or use `$v.email.$anydirty` to check if a value is invalid.
You can check out the values in Vue Devtools within the component's computed section. Should I provide a Screenshot?